# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'length'

Tags: qgis, python

I try to open the attribute table of a layer witch has a PythonInit fonction with a Ui form and returns "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'length'".
Made so far:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

amonte = None
aval = None
panta = None
layer = None
lungimeTextEdit = None
ValLungime = None
valoare = None
feature = None

def formOpen(dialog,layer,feature):
   global myDialog
   myDialog = dialog
   global lungimeTextEdit
   global amonte
   global aval
   global panta

   lungimeTextEdit = dialog.findChild(QLineEdit,"shape_leng")
   amonte = dialog.findChild(QLineEdit, "amonte")
   aval = dialog.findChild(QLineEdit,"aval" )
   panta = dialog.findChild(QLineEdit, "pente")
   buttonBox = dialog.findChild(QDialogButtonBox,"buttonBox")
   lungimeTextEdit.setText(str(feature.geometry().length()))
   buttonBox.accepted.disconnect(myDialog.accept)
```

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/python-attribute-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something

Comment: It gives me the error at the line:
 lungimeTextEdit.setText(str(feature.geometry().length())).
Could you be more explicit, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
amonte = None
aval = None
panta = None
ValLungime = None
lungimeTextEdit = None

def formOpen(dialog,layer,feature):
    global myDialog
    myDialog = dialog
    global amonte
    global aval
    global panta

if feature.geometry() is None:
    return

lungimeTextEdit = dialog.findChild(QLineEdit,"shape_leng")
amonte = dialog.findChild(QLineEdit, "amonte")
aval = dialog.findChild(QLineEdit,"aval" )
panta = dialog.findChild(QLineEdit, "pente")
buttonBox = dialog.findChild(QDialogButtonBox,"buttonBox")
lungimeTextEdit.setText(str(feature.geometry().length()))
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is thrown because you try to call the `length()` function for an object which doesn't exist. It could either be that the `geometry()` function of the current feature does not return anything or that the feature itself doesn't exist. Since you initialize the `feature` variable with a value of `None` it seems that no new value is assigned to the variable. You should ensure that a feature object is handed over to the `formOpen` function.

Comment: I just want to open the attribute table of the layer, and returns this error; so there is not on a feature creating. Any ideas ??

Comment: I also removed:
layer = None,
feature = None